# How to apply LINQ to ObjectResult<int?> when using EF 4.0?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Suppose I have a function call from EF like:

```
var result = context.myFunction();
```

the result type is  `ObjectResult<int?>`. Then I want to use linq to get the single value. 
How to write the linq?

Comment: Have you tried `result.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: In IntelliSense, there is no FirstOrDefault() or Single() available for type ObjectResult<int?>.

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` you your usings section. `FirstOrDefault` is an extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
result.SkipWhile(o => !o.HasValue).Take(1)
```

Comment: In IntelliSense,only these methods available: Dispose, Equals, GetEnumerator, GetHashCode, GetType, Tostring for type ObjectResult<int?>.

Comment: By the way if you need just first result then First() or FirstOrDefault() would be enough.